# about service accounts and unregistered users

Tags: google-drive-api

I have a web app in php mysql, I want to use one google drive account for my app.
Can I use my app's accounts instead of google users for privilages.
I read in SDK I can use service account to login without promting user, but I don't know  how to share or give permissions files for custom users.

In api reference I found [this](https://developers.google.com/drive/manage-sharing#ids_and_names):

"*The user is not necessarily yet a Google user (e.g. if a file or folder is shared with an email address that does not yet have an associated Google account). Example: 1111459233037698895607*".

How a custom user in my app should get a token for own privilages.

Answer (score 1):

I am not exactly sure what you want to achieve here, but if you want to use your own permission system, you can't. You can, however, apply read/write/owner permissions to files to mirror your own permissions.

If I have totally got the wrong idea, please explain.

Comment: thanks for the answer, i want to use one google-drive account but i have many users in myapp, i think it is not possible apply write permissions for different user. but is it possible if i use a google-script to open files, it can use JDBC, if i can pass a file-id,my-own-system-token in url than google-script can check permission from myserver,but i havent got an experience yet